How does Bitcoin Wallet know someone has sent you some money? Does it keep scanning blockchain continuously for transactions having your Public Key?
How does my wallet know that someone sent me some money as soon as the block containing the transaction gets mined? Does my wallet check for new blocks on the blockchain continuously 24x7x365? And every time it sees a new block does it scan each transaction in that block & check if any one of them have my public key in the ScriptPubKey part of the transaction?

From the comments on my answer, I got the impression that you may be asking about a specific wallet. Could you please clarify whether you are asking about a specific wallet software, one type of wallet, or wallets in general?

What you describe is what happens
If the wallet is not running 24/7 it will catch up by requesting missing blocks from peers.
See also SPV
